# Dynamically compile C# code on wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, runtime, compilation

I need to dynamically compile C# code in my WP7 app.

Normally i would use Microsoft.CSharp and System.CodeDom to compile the code during runtime, but they are unavailable on wp7 :(

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For security reasons you can't compile code on the phone. It would completely undermine the marketplace validation process & purpose if you could.

There are a few options though.

1. Use a dynamic language, such as IronRuby. Just like in [Iron7](http://zune://navigate/?appID=10aa051d-e907-e011-9264-00237de2db9e)
2. Compile the code on a remote server in response to what's defined in the app. Just like in [Pocket C#](http://zune://navigate/?appID=2f840483-0a54-e011-854c-00237de2db9e)
3. Or create your own DSL. Like in [Touch Studio](http://redirect.zune.net/External/LaunchZuneProtocol.aspx?pathuri=navigate?phoneAppID=fe08ccec-a360-e011-81d2-78e7d1fa76f8)

Comment: Thanks for the respone. Options 2 and 3 are a bit of an overkill in my case. I will investigate IronRuby.